# Cracking Playfair code

Tags: cryptography

I need to crack a Playfair encoded text without knowing the keyword. While searching the internet I found a way to do this using a 'shotgun climbing hill' method. Problem is, I can't decide how to quantify one solution against the other. I'm pretty sure the text is in English.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is encrypted text: http://pastebin.com/pEUXDvq1 .

Thanks for pointing me to pastebin.com.

Comment: Can you post the crypted text?

Comment: You have to analyse the probability of the letters.

Comment: e is usually rather typical, then t, then a (check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the text is more than 3,000 characters long. I can mail the text to you if you like, but I don't want to know the answer, I just want to know how it should be cracked (so basically, I would like to know the codeword).

Comment: To clarify: I want to know the answer, but the way to decode it is more important than the answer itself.

Comment: If need be, you can [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) the cipher-text...

Comment: Thanks, here is the text: http://pastebin.com/pEUXDvq1

Comment: It might be better to edit that into your question instead of keeping it in the comments... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I will give a fairly short answer, as this is homework you should figure out the details :-). To begin with the code is

> BDEWIKOCGHSMPQRZUVXYNFLAT

The decrypted text is a short story which be found on [this](http://www.alcyone.com/max/lit/flatland/1.html) website (formatted). You can use [this](http://cs.colgate.edu/faculty/nevison/Core139Web/tools/playfair.html) as a online tool for decrypting, still you will (of course) lose all formatting and find the position of the spaced of all words on your own. A detailed approach how to break Playfair can be found [here](http://www.umich.edu/~umich/fm-34-40-2/ch7.pdf), basically it tries to analyse the frequency of the letters which is of course harder when blocks are substituted instead of single characters.

Finally a ready-coded solver written in C can be found [here](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~burt/learning/Csc609.051/programs/playn/playn.c) (coded by J.W. Stumpel).
I hope that was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had already written a Delphi program to decode the text, but I couldn't figure out where it went wrong. The problem was, I didn't know what operations to use on the starting matrix and what stop criterion to use.

Comment: @user3123: I found the solution today, thanks for helping out. Studying the C-source from the link that was given, showed me how to calculate a meaningful stop condition. That helped me a lot because that was the main problem I was struggling with in the first place.

Comment: Good job, I am glad that I could help.